# Can Apache add an expires header onto a proxied resource?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a web app running off a WebLogic server, but the requests a proxied through Apache.  Some requests go to WebLogic, some go elsewhere.  There's a 100KB CSS file served from WebLogic that is dynamically generated, but rarely changes.  I would like that file to be cached for two hours at a time.

Is it possible for Apache to slap an expires header onto a WebLogic resource that it proxies?  If so, how do I set that up?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Location` directive for your web app directory and and add a `Header add Cache-Control "max-age=7200"` or `ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 hours"` inside of it.